# View portion of website through small iframe?

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, size

Is there a way to load a src url --say wikipedia.com --into a 320x240 iframe without the html reformatting itself to fit the bounds of the small iframe.  I want it to be the same size format it would be in a 1024x768 window, but only see a portion of it through the iframe window. The goal is to make it look like you are viewing a portion of a larger website through a tiny window.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 1024x768 `<iframe>` inside a 320x240 `<div>` with `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: Great. i would have never figured that out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Make the width and height equal to what you want in . The code in that iframe is completely determined by the remote site.  Some sites (one of my apps included) allows for a special CSS API call to be used in the iframe src tag to provide for the originating site to specify a different look and feel.